# After deployment the permissions are not the one i wanted

Tags: git, permissions, capistrano

I am using capistrano with git to deploy a RoR project. After deployment, the permissions in the current folder are 770 instead of 755, and it cause apache to display a forbidden page. My original folder where i work is using 755 as permissions. In my deploy.rb there is nothing about files permissions.

Why does capistrano change the permissions and how can i have correct permissions when deploying on my apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Capistrano, but git itself does not store any permissions, apart from the "executable" bit. You are supposed to achieve the expected permissions by setting an appropiate `umask` in your shell.

Comment: The only umask i founded does not use 770. I think git does not keep files ownership, but the permissions are stored, if i change a file permission, the change will appear in the next commit.

Comment: You where right, git only use 755 or 644. Anyway all my users have 0007 as umask but if i do a touch it create a 330 file (go figure). As git only store 644/755 capistrano must change the permission to 770 at some point.

Comment: @Sylario: I don't think you understand how a umask works - it's a mask. When you attempt to create a new file with given permissions, the result is the attempted permissions which are *not* in the mask. The umask that you want is `0022`, which will get you `755` for directories and executable files, and `644` for non-executable files.

Comment: i set umask 0022 in /etc/profile and ~/.bashrc but it still create 770 folders...

Comment: I changed umask and it works fine now. Umask may be in profile or in bashrc depending the User.

Comment: I think changing umask is a bad idea. Setting the correct permissions at the end of deployment is better IMO.

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post with the solution: http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/2012/07/26/capifony-fix-for-deployment-on-servers-with-strict-permission-settings/

Permission changes like that is usually caused by the default `umask` setting which is usually fine for normal usage. However some hosts require specific permissions (usually 755 for directories and 644 for files). This is mainly because of security reasons. The best thing you can do is to make this part of the deployment and set correct permissions.